# How to get sound to both headphones and USB speakers?

Tags: headphones, speakers

I have a USB Speakers and I want to record the sound from WNYC Radio to listening to it offline on my iPhone.

I'm able to alternate them, but not listening to both at the same time.

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: Multi-Output Devices in Audio MIDI Setup might be able to do that. It's not something i've ever tested. https://support.apple.com/kb/PH5178?locale=en_US [it's in Applications / Utilities, btw]  … on second thoughts - listening to both is totally different to recording the audio stream as it happens. dwightk's answer is the only app that will record a stream [any stream, any time - it's a great app, imnsho]

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Audio Hijack from Rogue Amoeba](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) does this, but I'm not certain. They have a free trial, so you can make sure that is possible before you buy it.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily done with an Aggregate Device as described here https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202000

Basically you combine multiple input/output devices into what appears to the OS to be a single device.